# Is it possible to retrieve the users profile using their membership user id?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, profile, membership, provider

Using the Asp.net Membership & Profile Providers:

Am I able to retrieve a user profile using their Membership UserID instead of their Username?

The reason I ask is because if I have the UserID and not the Username I would have to write the following two lines of code

```
    Dim MembershipUser As MembershipUser = Membership.GetUser("UserID")
    Dim Profile As Profile = Profile.GetProfile(MembershipUser.UserName)
```

Instead of:

Dim Profile As Profile = Profile.GetProfile("UserID")

Will this affect performance? Is my design bad? Am I missing something?

Please note: I am aware that I can retrieve the current logged in user using the following code: HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name

Answer (score 3):

```
Guid userId = Membership.GetUser().ProviderUserKey as Guid;
```

will give you the UserId that you're after. For simplicity in asp.net apps I normally stick in into session when user logs on.

The asp.net membership tables have unique username per application, and as it is possible to define multiple applications in one database it will also be possible for a call Profile.GetProfile( string userName ) to return a profile from different application. This is why there's no GetProfile( userName ) and it's a bad idea implementing it yourself.

Comment: I am building an ASP.Net Web Application and not a Website so I have used WebProfileBuilder 1.3. (As I don't really see any other way of doing it?)... I can successfully use: WebProfile.GetProfile(UserName) but there is no method to pass in the ID. Do I have to customize it?

Comment: If you create a New Website in visual studio and then add some properties i.e. <properties><add name="PostalCode" /></properties>. You can then retrieve that post code value for any user using the following code:  Profile.GetProfile("Username").PostalCode. So why are you saying that 'This is why there's no GetProfile(userName) and it's a bad idea implementing it yourself'?

Comment: It is not clear from your question what exactly it is that you actually want... Having a brief look at my asp.net app with vanilla asp.net membership I was asking these seriees of questions: "Will this affect performance? Is my design bad? Am I missing something?"

Comment: What I want to do is retrieve the profile for a user (not the logged in user) using a MembershipUserID rather than a Username.